# Does containsKey or get in Tree map uses binarySearch?

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap

Elements in the `TreeMap` are sorted and thus I tought that maybe `get(...)` or `containsKey(...)` uses binary search. Are those methods faster than those implemented in the `HashMap` and do they really use binary search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Not binary search but the complexity must be O(logn)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html):

> This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the containsKey, get, put and remove operations. Algorithms are adaptations of those in Cormen, Leiserson, and Rivest's Introduction to Algorithms.

Note it is in fact a Red-Black Tree:

> A Red-Black tree based NavigableMap implementation

But note that although I always hate to treat hash tables as O(1) data structure blindly, for almost all practical purposes HashMap is `O(1)`, unless: e.g., you choose a very bad hash function or massively overload the map.

Answer (score 3):

Open the documentation for the classes [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/TreeMap.html) and [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/HashMap.html), and you will get your answers.

In [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/TreeMap.html), it says:

> This implementation provides **guaranteed log(n) time cost for the `containsKey`, `get`, `put` and `remove` operations**. Algorithms are adaptations of those in Cormen, Leiserson, and Rivest's Introduction to Algorithms.

In [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/HashMap.html), it says:

> This implementation provides **constant-time performance for the basic operations (`get` and `put`)**, assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets.

As you can see, `HashMap` is *O(1)*, while `TreeMap` is *O(log(n))*, hence `HashMap` is faster.

You could read more about *hash tables* and *red-black trees* (the type of tree used by TreeMap) in the following Wikipedia entries:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree

On the right side of these articles, you can see a summary of the complexities of the most common operations on these structures.

Comment: The hashMap O(1) can be much slower than RBT O(log n): it mainly depend on n, and on the cost to compute the key hash w.r.t to comparing 2 keys. So you cannot conclude that hashmap is (always) faster.

Answer (score 1):

HashMap is faster. Its `get()` and `containsKey()` methods are O(1) (constant time, provided the hashCode is correctly implemented).

TreeMap's `get()` and `containsKey()` are O(log(n)), and they of course use the tree structure to make these operations fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in the implementation of OpenJDK 7, it's quite easy to understand. So yes, it's a binary search:

```
final Entry<K,V> getEntry(Object key) {
    // Offload comparator-based version for sake of performance
    if (comparator != null)
        return getEntryUsingComparator(key);
    if (key == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    Comparable<? super K> k = (Comparable<? super K>) key;
    Entry<K,V> p = root;
    while (p != null) {
        int cmp = k.compareTo(p.key);
        if (cmp < 0)
            p = p.left;
        else if (cmp > 0)
            p = p.right;
        else
            return p;
    }
    return null;
}

public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
    return getEntry(key) != null;
}
```

`getEntryUsingComparator` is the same binary search, just using a `Comparator` object.

Comment: That's not a binary search (at least not in the sense of Arrays.binarySearch()).

Comment: @JBNizet: it's a red-black tree (sorted binary search tree). I haven't compared it with `Arrays.binarySearch()`, which requires a pre-sorted array. But it basically executes the same algorithm, i.e. starts in the _middle_ and compares the key, then goes left or right.